# Logo image must adjust to height of header

Tags: css, header, resize, image-resizing, fluid-layout

Asking for advice: What would be the best way of making my website's (square) logo appear on or to the left of a fluid header?

My header takes up 100% of the width, but resizes in height depending on the viewport size. So I can't simply float the logo to the left of the contents, because then the image doesn't have the right height (and width, because it's square).

I tried setting the picture as background-image to the header, using:

```
background-position: left;

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: contain;
```

But the problem then is that it needs different paddings-left at different screen/viewport sizes.

[image]

Then tried putting display: table on the header and display: table-cell on the logo and header contents div, but then the header contents resize to the height of the logo rather than the other way around because the logo is the biggest element in line.

Here's the HTML (simplified):

```
<header>

  <div class="header-contents">

    <h1>Site title</h1>

    <nav>

  </div>

</header>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT / COMPLETELY DIFFERENT SOLUTION:

Style it as a CSS table, put the img in a DIV that's the left table-cell, give that a percentage width and auto height:

(Here in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXNyBe)

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="logo">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/fa0">
  </div>
  <div id="restofheader">
  <h1>My Headline</h1>
  </div>
</div>

#header {
  background: green;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

#logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#restofheader {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Addition, 2 Screenshots where this is applied to your site (with 20% logo width = header height - could be smaller or larger):

Large screen:

[image: large screen]

small screen:

[image: small screen]

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't resize the image to fit the header height. Note that the header doesn't have a fixed height, so the image is just displayed at 100% of the image height.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I'm afraid that doesn't do it, though. Making the image a certain percentage width of the header doesn't give it the right height. It needs to stay the same height as the header, whatever the header's height.

Comment: does the header have a fixed height? because if not (i.e. if the header height is proportional to the header width), it _does_ work. In fact here the logo height is proportional to the header width...

Comment: The header doesn't have a fixed height, no. But I don't want the logo height to be proportional to the header height. I want it to be exactly the same as the header height.

Comment: it's proportional to the header _width_, not height, and at the same time it's exactly the same as the header height. Have you looked at my codepen and changed the window width there?

Comment: Yeah, I copied-and-pasted your code exactly as you suggested, but it doesn't produce the desired effect, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can take a look live at http://atlanticsentinel.com, I'll keep it up for a few minutes for you

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshots! I wasn't sure how to. So what happens is that the logo is always 20 percent of the header width, hence it stretches the header vertically. I want it to be other way around: the logo is resized to the dynamic height of the header. Like in the screenshot in my opening post, except not have the site title and navigation overlay the image.

Comment: Reading your comments again, I think I realize where we wrong wrong: The header height is NOT proportional to the header width. The dynamic element in the header is the site-title and it has a font-size: 4vw

Answer (score 1):

```
.header-contents {
      background-image: url(yourimage);
      background-position: left center;
      background-size: auto 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

if it is not the answer your looking for, please provide a fiddle and a better explanation :)

Comment: That's more or less what I tried. Sorry if the OP wasn't clear, I added a screenshot of my site using the background-image approach. I hope it makes more sense that way.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done instead now is give fixed header heights for different resolutions. It seems totally fluid is not an option here.

The code, in case anyone's interested:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 568px) {

.site-branding {

    background: url('http://atlanticsentinel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Atlantic-Sentinel-logo.png');

    background-position: left;

    background-size: contain;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    height: 100px;

    padding-left: 115px; }

h1.site-title {

    font-size: 2em; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.site-branding {

    height: 120px;

    padding-left: 135px; }

h1.site-title {

    font-size: 3.2em; } }
```

If there is another option, please let me know! I would appreciate other ideas!

Thank you for your help!